# Caddy Server - HTTPS Request from local machine timesout

Tags: docker, ubuntu, ssl, firewall, caddy

I've been using Caddy for ages but I am setting up a domain on a new network and am having issues.

I have a domain pointed at Caddy and letsencrypt works, I can access my docker containers, I can access the services inside them, and HTTP -> HTTPS works (nearly.)

My issue is that I need to send an HTTPS request from the local machine to the domain in question, and have Caddy reverse_proxy to the correct service. When I perform this request from a remote machine, the request is redirected to HTTPS and everything works fine. But when I perform the request from the local machine hosting the server the 308 redirect from :80 to :443 is logged by caddy but the request on :443 timesout and Caddy doesn't log the request.

Caddy is running in a docker container on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine. I've enabled ufw rules, I've totally disabled ufw, I've tried iptables rules, I've tried sysctl forwarding, I've tried dnsmasq which gets the request to caddy (unfortunately the service I'm running conflicts with that). I've gone over the router being used, and hairpinning/NAT reflection seems to be working due to :80 being handled successfully.

I'm primed to believe its the firewall somehow disrupting the request, but I can't figure out how. I'm nearly ready to open wireshark because I'm totally stumped.

Remote Machine (different ISP from Host):

Caddy Logs

```
INF undefined | ts=1680984331.326366 logger=http.log.access.log0 msg=handled request request=[object Object] user_id= duration=0.000094674 size=0 status=308 resp_headers=[object Object] 
DBG undefined | ts=1680984331.5846565 logger=events msg=event name=tls_get_certificate id=e260df2f-c827-4620-9d92-3541c6c006ad origin=tls data=[object Object] 
DBG undefined | ts=1680984331.5849168 logger=tls.handshake msg=choosing certificate identifier={DOMAIN_NAME} num_choices=1 
DBG undefined | ts=1680984331.584952 logger=tls.handshake msg=default certificate selection results identifier={DOMAIN_NAME} subjects={DOMAIN_NAME} managed=true issuer_key=acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org-directory hash=26eeed.....8aad7f4a 
DBG undefined | ts=1680984331.5849729 logger=tls.handshake msg=matched certificate in cache remote_ip=*{REMOTE_WAN_IP}* remote_port=56236 subjects={DOMAIN_NAME} managed=true expiration=1688700111 hash=26eeed8d.....ad7f4a 
DBG undefined | ts=1680984331.648613 logger=http.handlers.reverse_proxy msg=selected upstream dial={DOCKER_CONTAINER}:9000 total_upstreams=1 
DBG undefined | ts=1680984331.6510875 logger=http.handlers.reverse_proxy msg=upstream roundtrip upstream={DOCKER_CONTAINER}:9000 duration=0.002419674 request=[object Object] headers=[object Object] status=200 
INF undefined | ts=1680984331.6516836 logger=http.log.access.log0 msg=handled request request=[object Object] user_id= duration=0.003096468 size=19090 status=200 resp_headers=[object Object]
```

CURL

```
*   Trying {HOST_WAN_IP}:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to {DOMAIN_NAME} ({HOST_WAN_IP}) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: {DOMAIN_NAME}
> User-Agent: curl/7.68.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Connection: close
< Location: https://{DOMAIN_NAME}/
< Server: Caddy
< Date: Sat, 08 Apr 2023 20:05:31 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Closing connection 0
* Clear auth, redirects to port from 80 to 443Issue another request to this URL: 'https://{DOMAIN_NAME}/'
*   Trying {HOST_WAN_IP}:443...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to {DOMAIN_NAME} ({HOST_WAN_IP}) port 443 (#1)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Encrypted Extensions (8):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, CERT verify (15):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.3 / TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN={DOMAIN_NAME}
*  start date: Apr  8 03:21:51 2023 GMT
*  expire date: Jul  7 03:21:50 2023 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "{DOMAIN_NAME}" matched cert's     "{DOMAIN_NAME}"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Let's Encrypt; CN=R3
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55a14b2588c0)
> GET / HTTP/2
> Host: {DOMAIN_NAME}
> user-agent: curl/7.68.0
> accept: */*
>
```

Host Machine:

Caddy Logs

```
INF undefined | ts=1680983971.422668 logger=http.log.access.log0 msg=handled request request=[object Object] user_id= duration=0.00003335 size=0 status=308 resp_headers=[object Object]
```

CURL

```
*   Trying {HOST_WAN_IP}:80...
* Connected to {DOMAIN_NAME} ({HOST_WAN_IP}) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: {DOMAIN_NAME}
> User-Agent: curl/7.81.0
> Accept: */*
>
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 308 Permanent Redirect
< Connection: close
< Location: https://{DOMAIN_NAME}/
< Server: Caddy
< Date: Sat, 08 Apr 2023 19:59:31 GMT
< Content-Length: 0
<
* Closing connection 0
* Clear auth, redirects to port from 80 to 443
* Issue another request to this URL: 'https://{DOMAIN_NAME}/'
*   Trying {HOST_WAN_IP}:443...
* connect to {HOST_WAN_IP} port 443 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to {DOMAIN_NAME} port 443 after 130480 ms: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 1
curl: (28) Failed to connect to {DOMAIN_NAME} port 443 after 130480 ms: Connection timed out
```

UPDATE: Obviously, disabling the HTTPS redirect allows the request to complete as normal without any TLS. I should have added, if I attach a service with self-signed SSL certs on a different port (ie :9443) the request completes normally, if I then attach the service to :443 it will similarly timeout.

UPDATE2: Tshark agrees with me. Local requests on 443 never get to my interface, port 80 is handled properly. Self-signed certs on other ports are handled correctly. Requests from remote IPs are handled correctly. ISP the problem?

Been really pounding my head on the wall on this one.

Thanks in advance,

Schmorrison